# if checkbox checked active else inactive in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

My view for checkbox is

```
    <td style="font-size:12px;">
 <a href="
<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/mark_active/<?php echo $callData['id_client'][$i]; ?>">
 <input type="checkbox" 
  <?php if ($callData['type'][$i]==3277379) echo 'checked="checked"'  ?>

> Active</a><br/>

 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/mark_inactive/
   <?php echo  $callData['id_client'][$i];  ?>">
 <input type="checkbox" 
 <?php if ($callData['type'][$i]==3277378) echo 'checked="checked"'  ?>
  > Inactive</a>

  </td>
```

My function is working fine. I have two checkbox. when I click on active it works like active button and when I click inactive it works like inactive button.

**But I want to use one checkbox.** Like when I click checkbox it will work like active and when the checkbox uncheck it will work like inactive. Please help me. Your cooperation will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your check box is

```
input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"
```

You have to take hidden variable in html code like

```
input type="hidden" id="flag" name="flag" value=""
```

Then when you check or uncheck the checkbox, you have to call onchange event in jquery for checkbox

```
$("#checkbox").onchange(function(){

      if($("#flag").val() == "" || $("#flag").val() == "Active"){
            $("flag").val("Inactive");
            ## here active button code
      }else if($("#flag").val() == "" || $("#flag").val() == "InActive"){
            $("flag").val("Active");
            ## here inactive button code
      }
 });
```

and if you want to call php function from jquery then you need to call ajax in that jquery code depending on active or inactive condition

Comment: you need to send ajax request to php file from jquery code, write the ajax request code where i write **#here active button code**  and **#here inactive button code** according to your requirement, for jquery ajax tutorial code you can check out this url http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Place your HTML in a div with id say **switchBox** and then try something like this:

```
$("#switchBox checkbox").click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $(this).text('Acvite');
        $("#switchBox").find('a').prop('href', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/mark_active/<?php echo $callData['id_client'][$i]; ?>");
    }else{
        $(this).text('Inacvite');
        $("#switchBox").find('a').prop('href', "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/mark_inactive/<?php echo $callData['id_client'][$i]; ?>");
    }
});
```